# Why does a fn of type A => B not allow x => x?

Tags: typescript

I don't understand why TypeScript does not allow the following:

```
type aToB = <A, B> (a:A) => B;
const id : aToB = x => x;
```

I get the error: Type A is not assignable to type B.

But the type definition `type aToB = <A, B> (a:A) => B` does not say in any way, that A has to be different from B.

At least in mathematics a function signature like `f: A -> B` does not demand `A` to be different from `B`. A function like `f: Nat -> Nat` would be a legitimate instance of `f: A -> B`.

Is TypeScript just weird in this way or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: The signature `f: A -> B` where A and B are free variables does in fact demand that free variables A and B must be different. In other words, in math, the statement "for any `A`, `B`  `A -> A` is an instance of `A -> B`"  is false.

Comment: @artem. No. Same name means the two things must be the same. Different names does not mean in any way that the two things must be different.

Comment: @TerenceS. yes, but different names does mean they may be different. So while `x=> x` is valid for some replacements of `A` and `B` it is not valid for ALL replacements. Same applies in TS.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir. Completely agree, they may be different. I just thought that i could put a more specific instance where a more general definition applies. But maybe I am confusing this with polymorphism.

Comment: @TerenceS. the second part of the  problem is outlined in my answer, who determines `A` and `B` since the caller does it `x => x` is not always valid

Comment: @Terence With generic variables, more specific type must be a subtype of general definition for all possible values of generic variables in both definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define a generic function. The idea with a generic function is that the **caller** decides the concrete types. So I could write:

```
type aToB = <A, B> (a:A) => B;
declare const id: aToB = x => x;
id<number, string>(0)
```

In the above example `id` is called with `number` and `string`, the signature defined by `aToB` allows this. But this would mean your implementation does meet the callers expectation that `id` should return a `string`. This is why typescript does not allow you to assign the function `x => x` to `id`.

You can define `aToB` to be generic, and then the generic types are determined when you assign the type to the variable:

```
type aToB<A, B> =  (a:A) => B;
const id: aToB<number, number> = x => x; // ok now
id(0) // generic types are already set
const id2: aToB<number, string> = x => x; // still would be an error
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Quick follow-up: I think `type aToB = <A, B> (a:A) => A|B`  seems to do what I want. Is this a bad idea?

Comment: @TerenceS. depends on your use case .. but seems like a bas idea.. in `type aToB = <A, B> (a:A) => B | A;
const id: aToB = x => x;
let d = id(0 + 1)` `d` will be `number | {}` which means you will need a type guard to do anything whith `d`